# Array of pointers vs Multidimensional Array

Tags: c

What the benefits and disadvantage of using an array of pointers vs a multidimensional array and vica verse in C or C++. They both seem the same to me.
For example, take the following

```
char *people[] = {"Alex", "Tom", "Peter"};
```

Versus

```
char people[][9] = {"Alex", "Tom", "Peter"};
```

Comment: "visa verse" is the 4-line part of a banker's poem about credit cards. The word you're looking for is "vice versa".

Answer (score 5):

multidimensional arrays are easier to work with, whereas pointer arrays sometimes result in a faster program.

multidimensional arrays cant be modified, pointer arrays can simply be changed to point elsewhere anytime.

**POINTER ARRAYS:**
[image: pointer arrays]
**MULTIDIMENSIONAL ARRAYS**
[image: multi-d arrays]

Not to mention those unused memory space, such a waste.

Comment: I dont have any photoshop or anything, so paint will do.

Comment: It is worth noting that it is definitely not a rule that pointer arrays are faster. Sure, they are less wasteful memory-wise, however if you consider the magic of CPU caching, and if your code is more query-heavy than creation-heavy, I would expect multidimensional arrays to totally outspeed pointer arrays.